# Tracing a pixel in a Picture

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I have a picture of a road like this

[image]

Now I want to look only at the bottom of the picture pic up the white lane marking on the left side and follow it till I cover the whole shape.

I don not want to use the findContour function cause I will get a lot of bad data and it's not time efficient to go through all the possibilities to figure the right one.

I want the algorithm to be fast so just follow and starting point on the bottom and go up and follow the line in the same picture.

Now my question is there any openCV functionality available to track a pixel or maybe a little dash line to follow the line?

What do you suggest? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This brings to mind Stanford's work on machine learning

Comment: You are saying the algorithm has to be fast. Is this just of theoretical Big-O interest, or do you have to get the data from an image like your example in a specific time in milliseconds? In that cases the programming language can be of interest. And of course the output format. What do you need? A list of all the pixels belonging to the left lane? Or the contour? Or a skeleton? You could show your solution with canny of findContours that produces the correct result but is too slow. Then we could try to optimize it.

Comment: I am writing my program in Erlang and using NIF functionality to run openCV functions, So you can assume that it is C++. I want the calculation to be done in less the 30 ms on Odroid X2 which has 2G ram and quadcore 1.3 CPU and it is arm base. The calculation with contours need to be recalculated to make sense out of the data and go through all of the Points, with houghline in the curve we get so many lines and the best case will be bird-eye picture which is also not efficient to bird-eye the whole picture. Thanks for your interest and comment

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What I still did not get is what data of the lane you exactly want to have. 1) all lane pixels, 2) contour pixels, 3) all pixels of the lane center, 4) coordinates defining the lane skeleton? http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zdja.jpg

Comment: Choice Number 3 is the winner :D Thanks again man

Comment: I guess if the color of the lane and the background is known approximately, and a pixel position that is on the line, it should be possible to get to option 2 oder 3 quite efficiently. What guarantees are made about the lane? Is the color quite constant? Is the lower left pixel in the image always on the lane? Or: If you would use the slow approach with findContours, how would you determine which of the found contours is actually the lane you are looking for?

Comment: we will do a lot of calculation on findContours with approxpoly and area and ... ! the picture is mostly good and there is no problem. after adding a gray scale and treshhold we will get the colors for white bigger than 175

Comment: edit: more readable version with line feeds: http://codepad.org/7Gudwzpr OK, so is it correct, that you would get along with a function doing the following?
input:
- grayscale image
- seed point
- threshold value
calculation:
- finding all pixels adjacent to the seed point that are brighter as the given threshold
- calculate the shape around these pixels
output:
- the shape of the segmented object
The critial point here is, that the seed point has to be given and must be inside the shape that should be segmented. But this condition is true, right?

Comment: Is my answer useful or do you need something else? :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dobi for all your help, but still you are using the findContours and I test it and still a lot slow. we are following some other approaches hope to work

Comment: Yes, I am still using findContours but not on the original (thresholded) image, but on an image that results from floodfilling. It only contains the one shape you are looking for ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/xPjTt.png ). And because this all takes only 1ms on my machine, I was hoping it will be below 30ms on your machine.

Comment: Did you find a fast enough solution? Perhaps shrinking the image to half the size is an option. The speedup for findcontours should be a factor of about 4. :)

Comment: @Dobi Hi again, We managed to create a new algo for this. We are publishing a paper on it soon. (we are not using opencv anymore)

Comment: Very cool. I am happy to hear that. I guess you will post the paper here then? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know a seed point the segmentation can easily and quite fast (about 0.001s on my current machine) be done via `floodFill`:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <boost/chrono/include.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> segment_lane(const cv::Mat& img, const cv::Point& seed, int tol)
{
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows + 2, img.cols + 2, CV_8UC1);
    cv::floodFill(img, mask, seed, 255, 0, cv::Scalar(tol, tol, tol), cv::Scalar(tol, tol, tol), 4 + (255 << 8) + cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY + cv::FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    cv::findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(-1, -1));
    return contours;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("Ph2PK.png");

    auto start = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto contours = segment_lane(img, cv::Point(21, 461), 40);
    auto end = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();

    boost::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";

    cv::drawContours(img, contours, 0, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::imwrite(out.png", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

If the following contour is not enough, try to adjust the tolerance values or leave out `FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE`.

[image: contour]